# How to limit associated work items in Azure DevOps YAML pipeline once PR is merged?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been migrating build/release pipelines in Azure DevOps to the unified YAML format. Everything works as expected apart from the work items which are associated with CI builds once a PR is merged to the master branch. Here is the workflow:

1. Developer raises PR to merge changes from feature branch into the master branch
2. The PR has a build policy which executes the YAML pipeline against a test environment
3. The PR is completed and the feature branch is merged into the master branch
4. The YAML pipeline has a CI trigger for deployments to higher environments

For step 2 the triggered build shows whichever work items are associated with the PR:

[image]

However, for Step 4 the triggered CI build lists all work items in the master branch rather than just those associated with the PR:

[image]

Is there a way to only associate the work items which are associated with the PR to the CI build which is triggered once the feature branch is merged into master?

Comment: Azure DevOps should automatically diff your merge to master and only associate the newly added work items. It sounds like you might have lost a common ancestor. Which type of merge are you performing when you merge into master?

Comment: We're using merge (no fast forward). This merge strategy works as expected in the old build & release pipelines; release pipelines were associated with the expected work items.

Comment: Hm, that's really strange then. That *should* work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue and I found a similar ticket, they have reported it, you could follow this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-linked-work-items-on-new-release-branche/1350859) to get the latest news.

If the build status is queue or running, then we create a new build, the new build will contain before build link work item. This is why the step 4 the triggered CI build lists all work items in the master branch rather than just those associated with the PR.

If all builds are completed, then we complete the pull request to trigger the CI build, it will be associated with the expected work items.

When all the builds were completed, I merged the PR to trigger the CI build, it just contain the pull request link work item.

Test result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your repro. Are you saying that this is the intended design? I.e. the linked work items for a (master) CI build show everything that hasn't been released? If that's true then I don't know how to recover from the situation I'm in. My latest CI build is showing 41 linked work items, however there are only ~5 which haven't yet been deployed to production...

Comment: I created the ticket he referred to. I recorded a video show exactly the problem with the linked work items being wrong: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/community/screencast/8b197afd-9aa6-43d0-9cdd-f65c8b2d6964
I currently have a work around where I simply fetch my previous successful build, find which PR is linked to it, and then get the work items from the PR.
Sadly you can't edit the already linked work items for the build (at least not that I see in the Devops RestAPI). I keep them separately and attach tags+update the "Integrated in Build" field, which then later I use for release notes.

Comment: Hi @RikDePeuter, this is not the intended design, and we have reported this issue, we could follow the ticket to get the latest news. In addition, according to the video, you could try to trigger the next CI build or PR trigger build when all previous builds are completed, then it will be associated with the expected work items.

Comment: I think this is a issue, and I just show the workaround to link expected work items instead of link all work items. I also follow the ticket, if there is any update, I will share it here.

Comment: Have you news about this behavior?